# Webpages are not wrapping

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure if this is enough information, please let me know if you need more. I'm very inexperienced so not sure what is necessary.

I have a section that is displayed on various web pages. For some reason it is not wrapping...the images and corresponding text areas all just keep running off the pages.

Here is the HTML. The are where I'm having trouble is just under `<hr style=" width: 114%;">`, the Block NewProducts, id: "HomeNewProducts".

```css
/* Product Listings */

.ProductList,
.ProductList li {
  horizontal-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0;
}

.Content .ProductList,
.Content .ProductList li {}

.ProductList li {
  list-style: none;
  min-height: 250px;
  width: 260px !important;
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: 1em;
  /*margin-right: -1px;*/
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#home .Content ul.ProductList li {
  width: 260px !important;
}

.ProductList .ProductPriceRating {
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.ProductList .ProductImage,
.brand-img {
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* border: 1px solid #d4d3d3; */
}

.ProductList .ProductImage img {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  max-width: 270px;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<!-- HEAD GOES HERE -->

<body>
  <div id="Container">
    <div><img src="http://www.somethingorother.com" />&nbsp; LoadingPleaseWait
    </div>
    <div id="Outer">
      <div id="TopMenu">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div class="phoneIcon">CALL US</div>
          </li>
          <li>Some line of other</li>
          <li class="last CartLink" style="display:HideCartOptions">
            <a href="some url or other" title="View This"><i class="icon" title="View Cart">&nbsp;</i><span>Items / $0.00</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <br class="Clear">
      </div>
      <div id="Header" class="clearfix">
        <div id="Logo">
          HeaderLogoGoesHere
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <div id="SearchForm">
            <form action=".../search.php" method="get" onsubmit="return check_small_search_form()">
              <label for="search_query">Search</label>
              <input type="text" name="search_query" id="search_query" class="Textbox autobox" value="Search" />
              <input type="submit" class="Button" value="" name="Search" title="Search" />
            </form>
          </div>
          <script type="text/javascript">
            var QuickSearchAlignment = 'right';
            var QuickSearchWidth = '390px';
            lang.EmptySmallSearch = "EmptySmallSearch";
          </script>

        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="Wrapper">
        <div class="Left fleft" id="LayoutColumn1">
          <div class="CategoryList" id="SideCategoryList">
            <div class="BlockContent">
              <div class="SideCategoryListClass">
                <li class="LastChildClass"><a href="CategoryLink">CategoryName</a>
                </li>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Content Wide" id="LayoutColumn2">
          <script type="text/javascript" src=".../javascript/jquery/plugins/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(window).load(function() {
              $('.slide-show').flexslider({
                slideshowSpeed: $('.slide-show').attr('data-swap-frequency') * 1000,
                animation: "slide",
                pauseOnHover: true,
                controlNav: true,
                directionNav: true
              });
            });
          </script>
          <div class="slide-show slide-show-render slide-show-render-full" id="HomeSlideShow">
            <ol class="slides">
              <li class="slide" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
                <a href="Slide_Link_Url">
                  <div class="slide-content">
                    <div class="slide-overlay">
                      <h2 class="slide-heading" style="color: #000">Slide_Heading_Text</h2>
                      <p class="slide-text" style="color: #000">Slide_Text_Text</p>
                      <p class="slide-button" style="Slide_Button_Hide"><span style="color: #000">Slide_Button_Text</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <span class="slide-image-wrapper">
         <img class="slide-image" src="Slide_Image_Url" alt="Slide_Image_AlternateText">
        </span>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ol>
          </div>
          <hr style="width: 114%;">
          <div class="Block NewProducts Moveable Panel" id="HomeNewProducts" style="display:HideHomeNewProductsPanel">
            <div class="BlockContent">
              <ul class="ProductList">
                <li class="AlternateClass">
                  <div class="ProductImage" data-product="ProductId">
                    <img src="http://www.somethingorother.com" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="ProductDetails">
                    <a href="Product_Link" class="pname">ProductName</a>
                    <em class="p-price">ProductPrice</em>
                    <div class="ProductPriceRating">
                      <span class="Rating Rating4"><img src=".../ProductRating.png" alt="" /></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ProductActionAdd" style="display: HideActionAdd;">
                      <a href="ProductURL" class="btn icon-ProductAddText " title=" ProductAddText "> ProductAddText</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>%
              </ul>
              <br class="Clear" />
            </div>
            <br class="Clear" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>

      </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you have an example somewhere? Hard to figure anything out without the HTML.

Comment: I think you need to post the HTML that this relates to.

Comment: I have edited the post to include the HTML that corresponds to my CSS. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured this out....was just a matter of my Wrapper and Container dimensions being out of whack. Adjusted the sizes and everything now lines up perfectly.